# Database records with different types

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to come up with a database table design for an event invitation list.  Suppose I have a membership table (memberId, memberName), and a memberGroup table (groupId, memberId).

```
Membership:
(1, John)
(2, Adam)
(3, Michelle)
(4, Donna)

MemberGroup:
(1, 1)
(1, 2) // John and Adam
```

Now, I want to create an invitation list table that I can populate with

```
memberGroupId = [1], memberId = [3,4]
```

and a free input (eg. "Ronald").

So the invitation list table needs to be able to take in these 3 types.  What would be the best way to design this table?  Should I have (memberGroupId, memberId, name[varchar]) as my columns where for each row only one of them would be populated?  That would require the program to be checking which type is being used for each row.  Or is there a better way to design something like this?

Comment: A normalized design seems appropriate.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to give every group a name. You can do this with 3 tables

```
members       (memberId, memberName)
groups        (groupId, groupName)
group_members (groupId, memberId)
```